# Was interest rate in Brewster's Millions that high?

Tags: realism, brewsters-millions

I was rewatching the movie [*Brewster's Millions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_Millions_(1985_film)) (1985) the other day and there's this one scene that caught my attention: when the title character goes to check out his 30 millions at the bank the person in charge tells him he will get the "special interest rate" of 24% a year.

Is this a realistic value for that time? Nowadays the interest rate is less than 1%. Were the eighties banks that generous? Or is this a normal value for very wealthy accounts, even today?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Bank of England interest rate](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/Bank-Rate.asp) (which is a base rate, not the same as you'd get on the high street) peaked at 17% in 1979 but was still around 15% in the early to mid 80s. It's currently at a mere 0.75%.

So yes, interest rates were massive at that time.

<sup>The Bank of England is not a high street bank, btw, it's the authority behind all the money in the UK. Basically, they do ***actually*** have a licence to print money ;)</sup>

Comment: Here's a graph of US interest rates which peaked at almost 20% in the early eighties:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_funds_rate#/media/File:U.S._Treasuries.png